# Approximation Methods in Physics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, approximations, textbook-erratum

There is this one statement in my physics textbook that I didn't quite get for finding out how much change in the time period of a [pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum) occurs due to a small change in its length, due to thermal expansion or ageing:

$$\Delta T = T - T_{0}  = 2 \pi  \left(\sqrt{\frac{g}{L+\Delta L}} -\sqrt{\frac{g}{L}} \right)$$

It says that

> the equation is exact but gives little to no info on how the change in $\Delta$T is affected by change in L and for $\Delta$L << L since it is the difference of two large numbers,

but to me isn't the difference clear, there is a small change in $\Delta$T as the difference is clearly small due to adding a small term and even that to the denominator.

Why does the textbook say that it is numerically inaccurate?

---

Here's an image of the passage from the textbook, [Kleppner and Kolenkow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ4Uo.jpg)*

*Note from editor that the equation is pulled from the textbook, even though it is incorrect.

Comment: What is the equation given in your textbook?

Comment: Was your textbook stating some version of the following? For a simple pendulum, the period is $T=2\pi \sqrt{g/L}$. Therefore, if we change the length from $L$ to $L+\Delta L$, then the period will change from $T$ to $T+\Delta T$, where $\Delta T = 2\pi\sqrt{g}\left(1/\sqrt{L+\Delta L}-1/\sqrt{L}\right)$. While exact (for a simple pendulum), this formula is unnecessarily precise if $\Delta L\ll L$, and a good approximation in this limit is $\Delta T = - \pi \sqrt{g/L} (\Delta L/L)$ (apologies in advance if I made a sign or factor of 2 error).

Comment: @Andrew, the time period of a simple pendulum is $T = 2 \pi\sqrt{L/g}$ not $2\pi\sqrt{g/L}$

Comment: Fair enough, I should have been more skeptical of what the OP wrote :) The general question still stands though -- it's not clear to me what the OP is asking, but I'm wondering if they are confused about the $\Delta L \ll L$ limit.

Comment: FWIW, even the proper formula (given by Cross) isn't exact. It's derived using the small angle approximation, $\sin\theta\approx\theta$. The exact formula involves an elliptic integral.

Comment: @Andrew, I agree! Even I feel like the OP is unaware of approximations using derivatives for infinitesimal changes (excluding the incorrect formula of course).

Comment: @Cross Oh I never realized that the formula given in the textbook was wrong, because I just blindly copied it from the book assuming it should not have a error in it since it is from Kleppner and Kolenkow. Here is the extract from that page: https://imgur.com/pnKbLj1

Comment: @Destiny-wolf, Wow that is a serious problem. Try to verify it yourself using dimensional analysis.

Comment: Apart from that, do you have a doubt in how the approximations are made for limits like $\Delta L << L$?

Comment: @Cross I don't know how to make such approximations,but anyhow the book does explain it in the next pages, My main concern was that the book says that we cannot gather enough info on the dependency on $\Delta$L on $\Delta$T as in we don't know if $\Delta$T is big or small, but isn't it clearly small, even in the correct formula for the time period?

Comment: If you use approximations you can get a linear dependency of $\Delta T$ on $\Delta L$. If you choose to use it directly without approximation, you get $\Delta T \propto \sqrt{L + \Delta L} - \sqrt{L}$, which is not linear and very sensitive to small changes in $\Delta L$. This is the only possible explanation I can think of.

Comment: The words "small difference of two large numbers," is not saying the numbers are very large, it's a statement that the numbers are so close that the difference might be rounded to zero if blindly put into a calculator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's leave aside the evident mistake in the formulae ($L/g \rightarrow g/L$) so that the formula should be read as
$$
\Delta T = T-T_0=\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{g}}\left(\sqrt{L+\Delta L}- \sqrt{L}  \right),
$$
What the textbook is saying is that the formula gives *little insight as to how $\Delta T$ depends on $\Delta L$*. I wouldn't consider equivalent *little insight* and *little to no info*. It is written that the full info is there but in a form, making it hard to see the consequences of a change of length on the change of period immediately. For instance, it is not easy to extract the consequence of doubling a given $\Delta L$.

A second criticism of the formula is that for small $\Delta L$, it corresponds to the difference of two almost equal numbers. Such a situation is known in Numerical Analysis as *subtractive cancelation*, or *[catastrophic cancelation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation)*, or *[loss of significance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance)*. In practice, when working with a finite number of decimal figures,  most of them are equal and disappear in the subtraction, leaving a result with a much lower number of significant figures, thus with lower relative precision.

Both drawbacks can be cured by using a small $\Delta L$ expansion of the square root:
$$
(1+x)^\frac12 \simeq 1+ \frac12x + O\left(x^2\right),
$$
giving
$$
\Delta T = 2 \pi\sqrt{\frac{L}{g}}\frac{\Delta L}{2L}.
$$
Or, even better
$$
\frac{\Delta T}{T_0}=\frac{\Delta L}{2L}
$$
Such a formula is exact within $O\left( \left(\frac{\Delta L}{L}\right)^2 \right)$ corrections, and makes it evident that the change of period is linear in the change of length. For example, if the length changes of $2\%$, the period changes of $1\%$. Moreover, it does not suffer from the subtractive cancelation phenomenon.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks, I'll add some other common names for the same numerical phenomenon.